# How to reduce multiple if not condition in single line or less code in python?

Tags: python

I have the python code which needs to reduce the if condition in single line or less number of lines.

```
if not Apple:
    error = 'Missing "Apple"'
if not Mango:
    error = 'Missing "Mango"'
if not Banana:
    error = 'Missing "Banana"'
if not Avocado:
    error = 'Missing "Avocado"'
if not Blackberries:
    error = 'Missing "Blackberries"'
elif not Blueberries:
    error = 'Missing "Blueberries"'
elif:
    error = 'No "Fruits"'
```

Is there a way to reduce the code.

```
a if cond else b
```

I can write it for if else condition but how do we reduce such long code?

Comment: some of the conditions are `if` and some are `elif`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the question? what you do you want to check?

Comment: Also, the final `elif` is illegal - did you mean `else`? But that doesn't make sense either...

Answer (score 1):

Some rough solution would be to make a collection out of your variables and store the captions (names) you want to display too. You then iterate the collection and test each component one by one.

```
fruits = {'Apple':Apple, 'Mango':Mango, 'Banana':Banana, 'Avocado':Avocado, 'Blackberries':Blackberries, 'Blueberries':Blueberries}
error = 'No "Fruits"'
for name, fruit in fruits.items():
    if not fruit:
        error = f'Missing "{name}"'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function, which check if fruit is not in list of fruits and give error based on that

```
def func(fruit):
    fruits = ["Apple", "Mango", "Banana","Avocado", "Blackberries", ]
    error = 'not fruits'  if  fruit not in fruits else f'Missing {fruit}'
    return error


func('Apple')
```

output

```
'Missing Apple'
```

Comment: Thanks sahasrara62 for such easy code but I'm getting error as "name 'val' is not defined". Can you please help me out, where am i missing. Thanks in advance! appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @Dave sory, i had used val as variable name, but changed it to fruit, but unable to do one case that time, solution is updated now and you can solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use this logic shown in the code below:

```
fruits_full = ["Apple", "Mango", "Banana", "Avocado"]
fruits_look_for = ["Apple", "Banana", "Ananas", "Water melon"]

for fruit in fruits_look_for:
    if not fruit in fruits_full:
        print("Missing {} in the list".format(fruit))
```

Basically just iterate thorough the list of string that you are looking for and check if they are in the full list.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [XY problem.](https://xyproblem.info/)

But depending on your needs you can make use of locals()

```
required_args = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
for arg in set(required_args)-set(locals())
    print(f'Missing {arg}')
```